# Does iterating through a large data set in a Map each time i click impact the performance?

Tags: java, android

I need to get values from a Map by Adapter position i get from a RecyclerView.

As you can see each time i click on an Album Art i create a new array of album objects.

```
final Album[] albums = new Album[albumMap.size()];
      for (Map.Entry<Integer,Album> e : albumMap.entrySet()){
      albums[i++] = e.getValue();
 }
```

Then i get the album like this: `String selectedAlbum = albums[position].getAlbum();`

But what if someone has like 10000+ albums on his device and each time an album is clicked a new array of album objects is created and i **iterate** through it just to get the album name.

Would this have an impact on performance if there are alot of albums present?

**TL;DR** Is this code bad?

**Full code**

```
@Override
    public void onClickAlbum(int position, Map<Integer,Album> albumMap) {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            int i = 0;
            final Album[] albums = new Album[albumMap.size()];
            for (Map.Entry<Integer,Album> e : albumMap.entrySet()){
                albums[i++] = e.getValue();
            }
            String selectedAlbum = albums[position].getAlbum();
            Main.getInstance().setSongsFilteredBy(SongsLibrary.getInstance().getSongsByAlbum(selectedAlbum));
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ListSongsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", selectedAlbum);
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test: " + selectedAlbum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

Comment: Of course that will give you a performance hit, but maybe less than you expect. Check how hash maps affect performance. BTW 10000 is a mickey mouse number of records.

Answer (score 2):

#### Technical improvements

- use `albumMap.values()` to get a `Collection<Album>` directly instantiated as list, which supports positional access `get(index)`. So no need for array and filling loop. See *Listing 1*.
- use some of Android's *ListView* interfaces which usually provide a convenient method on their underlying *data model* like `getItemAtPosition(position)`. See *Listing 2*.

*Listing 1*: [Q: How to convert map to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026723/how-to-convert-a-map-to-list-in-java)

```java
List<Album> albums = new ArrayList<Album>(albumMap.values());
```

*Listing 2*: [Vogella's Tutorial on Android's ListView](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_adapterlistener)

```java
ListView albumsView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

// fill albums data to model (adapter implementation)
albumsView.setAdapter(adapter)

albumsView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
    final Album album = (Album) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    // your implementation
  }
}
```

#### Design improvements

- `album.getAlbum()` gets the *title* of an album, so **rename** property|getter to `title`|`getTitle()`
- keep the event-handler short and **extract** all *action/intend creation* into separate method

#### References

- [Answer on using RecycleView with OnItemClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40584425)
- [Tutorial: Android working with RecyclerView](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)
- [Android Official Guide on AdapterView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Android so I don't know how you get albumMap into the click event. Can you get selected Album (album object) into the event?

If not..

I assume albumMap is a map between position to Album.

If so I suggest the name postion2album. if not please update your post and clarify what this map is.

So all you need to do is albumMap[position].getAlbum()